# MongoDB Aggregate limiting records returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following 3 collections schema in my Node.js app

```
Users{
_id
Name
}

Vendors{
_id
userId
CompanyName
}

CustomerFavoriteVendors{
_id
customerId
vendorId
}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve a list of all Vendors, while displaying their full user details as well as if they are Favorited by currently logged in customer, so I've built the following vendors aggregate function yet I can only retrieve vendors whom were Favorited, so I am wondering what I am missing here to retrieve all vendors despite if they were favorited or not? Thanks for your effort and support

```
let size = 10;
let offset = 0;
let query = [];

query.push(
{ $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "userId", foreignField: "_id", as: "userdetail"  } },
{ $unwind: "$userdetail" }, 
{ $lookup: { from: "customerfavoritevendors", localField: "_id", foreignField: "vendorId", as: "customerfav"  } },
{ $unwind: "$customerfav" },        
{ $group: { _id: null, content: { $push: '$$ROOT' },count: { $sum: 1 } } },
{ $project: { content: { $slice: [ '$content', offset, size ] }, count: 1, _id: 1 } },
);

const vendorsList = await Vendors.aggregate(query);
```

Comment: You try add  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true into your $unwind

Comment: ```{ $unwind: "$userdetail", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }, ``` and

Comment: ```{ $unwind: "$customerfav", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }, ```

Comment: Phong Thanks a lot for your effort but unfortunately this didn't solve the problem :(